# loading Yii Bootstrap in a module only

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I'm try to load the Yii Bootstrap extension in the admin module only but it's not working. I'm assuming I need to preload it or initiate it somehow... Thanks!

```
    class AdminModule extends CWebModule
    {
        public function init()
        {
            // import the module-level models and components
            $this->setImport(array(
                'admin.models.*',
                'admin.components.*',
                'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
            ));
        }

        public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
        {
            if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action))
            {
                         $this->layout = 'admin';                
                         return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in what way is it not working?

Comment: its not loading the css etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 4 different ways to do this:

1. Add the configuration to the app's configuration (*protected/config/main.php*):

   ```
   'modules'=>array(
       'admin'=>array(
           'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
           'components'=>array(
               'bootstrap'=>array(
                   'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'
           )
       ),
   // ... other modules ...
   )
   ```
2. Preload it in the `init` :

   ```
   public function init()
   {
       // import the module-level models and components
       $this->setImport(array(
           'admin.models.*',
           'admin.components.*',
           // 'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap', // this will go to app config for components
       ));
       Yii::app()->getComponent('bootstrap');// this does the loading
   }
   ```
3. Preload in `init` another way:

   ```
   public function init()
   {
       // import the module-level models and components
       $this->setImport(array(
           'admin.models.*',
           'admin.components.*',
       ));

       $this->configure(array(
               'components'=>array(
                   'bootstrap'=>array(
                       'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'
                   )
               )
       ));
       $this->getComponent('bootstrap');
   }
   ```
4. Preload in `init` yet another way:

   ```
   public function init()
   {
       // import the module-level models and components
       $this->setImport(array(
           'admin.models.*',
           'admin.components.*',
       ));

       $this->configure(array(
               'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
               'components'=>array(
                   'bootstrap'=>array(
                       'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'
                   )
               )
       ));
       $this->preloadComponents();
   }
   ```

Comment: I still get error Property "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined. when using either of your examples :( Is it because I store bootstrap files inside module extensions?

Comment: @dzona, you can do this even if you have bootstrap within a module's _extensions_ directory(I just tried it). you'll have to give more details about the code you have(and the line which generates that error), and the configuration of your directories, and also the version of your bootstrap, for me to be able to precisely point out the problem. But otherwise see if you have correctly accessed the extension(used correct alias - `module_name.extensions.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap`), wherever you are trying to initialize the extension's class.

Comment: this is my module init 
_function init()
if (!Yii::app()->hasComponent('bootstrap')) {
            Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__) . '/extensions/bootstrap');
            Yii::createComponent('bootstrap.components.Bootstrap')->init();
            Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();
        }_
and when I try to preload it with
Yii::app()->getComponent("bootstrap");
I get that error (Property "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined), if I didn't created bootstrap component in main config

Comment: @dzona, you said you used my examples, but your code is completely different :) . Try and use my code and it will work for u for sure.

Comment: @bool.dev I just tried all these examples again,with same result:
Property "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined. 
Code breaks when TbGridView.php(line 96) tries to get bootstrap component.
CModule->__get('bootstrap')
 No matter what I do, It seems like I must have bootstrap component in app main config defined :( Bootstrap ver is 1.10, and only thing I can currently think of,is maybe because I have multiple config files merging, and maybe some of them overwrite myModule config. but even in that case,your examples #3 and #4 should work, right? :-/ I'm using yiiboilerplate folder structure

Comment: @dzona, yes exactly 3 and 4 should definitely work. anyway the problem here is that it is saying that "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined, whereas it should say "YourModuleName.bootstrap" is not defined. So try with `Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', 'path-to-bootstrap');$this->setComponent('bootstrap', array('class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'));$this->bootstrap->register();`.

Comment: I use yiibooter extension, To load component in module init: 
`public function init()
{
    $this->getComponent('booster');
}` .And you can preload it without initiate in init(): 
`'gallery'=>array(
            'galleryDir'=>'images', //Default: images
            'preload'=>array('booster'),
            'components'=>array(
                'booster'=>array(
                    'class'=>'ext.yiibooster.components.Booster',
                    'yiiCss'=>false,
                    'forceCopyAssets'=>true,
                ),
            ),
        ),`

Answer (score 2):

When you configure the following in the main config (protected/config/main.php), example as:

```
'admin' => array(
      'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
       'components'=>array(
          'bootstrap' => array(
               'class' => 'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
               'responsiveCss' => true,
           ),
       ),
 )
```

Then, you can using component as

```
$bootstrap = $this->getModule()->bootstrap; // with $this is a current controller.
```

To define this module component to **main component**, you must to set Component in init() of Module class:

```
// Set main component `bootstrap`  instead of CController->getModule()->bootstrap
app()->setComponent('bootstrap', $this->bootstrap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Really working code : 
in your module init function just paste the following code :

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.bootstrap'));
Yii::app()->setComponent('bootstrap', array('class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected/config/main.php

'modules'=>array(
    'admin'=>array(
        'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
        'components'=>array(
            'bootstrap'=>array(
                'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap'
        )
    ),

)
```

Preload it in the init :

```
public function init()
{
    // import the module-level models and components
    $this->setImport(array(
        'admin.models.*',
        'admin.components.*',
        // 'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap', // this will go to app config for components
    ));
    Yii::app()->getComponent('bootstrap');// this does the loading
}
```

If it doesn't work then paste your url 
into that file, which form you are using bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/pojects/fcorginal/assets/b2e88ad5/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```