# link a bootstrap to a certain module

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, module

I have difficulty in connecting the bootstrap to a module. The bootstrap location is at: mainFolder/protected/extensions/bootstrap/theme/abound

protected/config/main.php

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

'modules'=>array(
    'admin',
    'consultant'=>array(
        'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
        'components'>array(
            'bootstrap'=>array(
                'class'=>'bootstrap.theme.abound'              
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'candidate',
),
```

protected/modules/consultant/ConsultantModule.php

```
class ConsultantModule extends CWebModule
{    
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setImport(array(
            'consultant.models.*',
            'consultant.components.*',
        ));

        Yii::app()->getComponent('bootstrap');          
    }
}
```

structure of the folder:

```
mainFolder
  protected
    config
      **main.php**
    extensions
      bootstrap
        assets
        components
        form
        gii
        theme
          **abound**
        widgets
    modules
      consultant 
        controllers
        models
        views
      **ConsultantModule.php**
```

Error that I get when I run the code:

```
Property "ConsultantModule.0" is not defined.
```

Is it because the properties inside the module's consultant is wrong or the way I place the bootstrap is not correct? I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: I hope this help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844509/loading-yii-bootstrap-in-a-module-only

Comment: And you have an error in your config. Change 'components'>array... to 'components' => array... You forget '='.